# jQuery & touch devices like iPad: addClass method and preventDefault

Tags: jquery, ipad, touch

When you listen for the touch events (touchstart, touchmove, touchcancel, touchend) on a touch device like the iPad, and in your touchstart eventhandler you are invoking *preventDefault()*, is it possible to add or remove classes in order to change the visible appearance of the touched element?  When I try to add a class at that juncture, there's no visible change -- because preventDefault was invoked?

One other thing:  the touched element does not (and must not) become the activeElement.

Use case: I'm trying to create an auxiliary virtual keyboard to display keys that are missing from the iPad's virtual keyboard, and would like to give some visible feedback when one of my keys is touched.  Each character is contained in a DIV. A text-input remains the activeElement.

Thanks

P.S. I know about Sencha.